# best practices execute external programs in Java web apps

Tags: java, servlets, grails, execute

I have a java app (in fact it is grails) I need to execute an external program. Preferably I want my app to be self-contained, i.e. the external scripts/programs to be part of the war file. This external script/program also needs to produce some files.

I guess, my question is if there is some kind of best practices how to do these sort of things so that the final product is not too flaky depending on app permissions and what not?

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you need to ensure that, only one thread executes an instance of your program at a time. so you need some locking and synchronization there.

Imagine a scenario where multiple users/requests/threads trying to execute the same program with different input, that will be a disaster. so you either need to lock the program while one is executing and others wait, or you need to create new instances everytime you want to run the program. you should be very careful about this.

Also, you want to clean up after the program runs and if it produces any output.

You need to be careful if the user can pass malicious commands to your system and tries to hijack other applications.

Overall, you have to be careful about security and correctness (the first scheme i mentioned.)

Answer (score 0):

Security - ensure that your app does not allow for the execution of arbitary (user supplied) code on the host system. Think SQL-Injection style attacks. If you need to pass around data, I suggest inserting it into a database first and then passing the primary key to your external process, this will help avoid buffer overflow type situations.

Robustness - can this program fail, or take along time, or have other unknown side effects. Isolate your main web app from this program by executing from a different thread, or even a different process.

Logging - if you need to collect logging from this external app, you may want to pass in a session id (or equivalent) so you can track back any errors to web sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You could design a small administrative system that will track service requests. It would be a very useful component, as most projects have a purpose like this.

The app should be executed from a service, the request to that service itself should be asynchronous. Also on top of this you can get feedback and track that service status.